# install C++ "X64 Compiler and Tools" on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: compilation, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit

I'm trying to run LevelZap on Windows 10 and the readme states the following:

In order to build all targets, make sure to install the x64 Compiler and Tools

I've gone to Control Panel → Visual Studio Community → Change/Modify but this particular category isn't listed that I can find. A little help please?

Comment: Which 'workloads' do you have selected for your VS 2017 install? The x64 tools are installed as part of a number of them, including the "Desktop development" workload.

Answer (score 1):

Run the "Visual Studio Installer" which is a desktop app (the same thing is launched by the Modify/Change button you hit).

Select "Modify" for your *Visual Studio Community 2017* install.

Select the "Individual components" tab.

Under the section *Compilers, build tools, and runtimes* you can verify you have "VC++ 2017 version 15.x v14.x latest v141 tools" selected. If not, select it and hit **Modify**.

This component includes booth the x86 and x64 toolsets. Only the ARM and ARM64 toolsets are split out as individual components.

> For more on the VS 2017 installer, see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/22/the-lightweight-visual-studio-15-installer/).

That said, the tool you are using needs to actually supporting finding the toolsets for VS 2017, so the problem way well be in the other software and not your system setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the build tools for Visual Studio 2017 using one of the installers from the website https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/